# Close all windows except for the starting window in tkinter

Tags: user-interface, tkinter

In this code below, I made a simple route guidance by opening defined windows each time I press a specific button e.g.) Mainmenu -> Classroom Floor -> Classroom No.

I'm trying to make a 'Home' button that will close all open windows except for the first Main Menu window with WELCOME written.

For example, after I press *btn7, btn702,* then I have 4 windows open. I would like to add a 'Home' button that will close 3 newly open windows and leave the first window alive. How might I make this kind of button?

```
from os import system
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

mainmenu = Tk()
mainmenu.title("CAU 310 GUIDE MAP")
mainmenu.geometry("1280x800+0+0")

canvas = Canvas(mainmenu, width = 1280, height = 800)
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand = True)

canvas.create_text(640, 250, text = 'WELCOME', font=times 45)

btnclassroom = Button(mainmenu, padx=5, pady=5,text="Classroom", font="times 30", command=selectfloor)

btnclassroom.place(x=140, y=570)


def selectfloor():
    mainmenu = Tk()
    mainmenu.title("DESTINATION")
    mainmenu.geometry("1280x800+0+0")
    mainmenu.config(bg='white')

    canvas = Canvas(mainmenu, width = 1280, height = 800)
    canvas.pack(fill='both', expand = True)
    
    canvas.create_text(640, 150, text = 'Select floor of classroom', font='Arial 40')

    btn7=Button(mainmenu, padx=4, pady=4, text="7F", font="Arial 42 bold", command=floor7)
    btn7.place(x=160-5, y=490)

def floor7():
    mainmenu = Tk()
    mainmenu.title("FLOOR 7")
    mainmenu.geometry("1280x800+0+0")

    canvas = Canvas(mainmenu, width = 1280, height = 800)
    canvas.pack(fill='both', expand = True)

    canvas.create_text(640, 150, text = 'Select classroom No.', font='Arial 40')

    btn702=Button(mainmenu, padx=3, pady=3, text="No.702", font="Arial 38 bold", command=room702)

    btn702.place(x=100+220*1, y=240)

    mainmenu.mainloop()

def room702():
    mainmenu = Tk()
    mainmenu.title("Elevator 1")
    mainmenu.geometry("1280x800+0+0")

    lobby = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("1F_elevator1.jpg"), master=mainmenu)

    canvas = Canvas(mainmenu, width = 1280, height = 800)
    canvas.pack(fill='both', expand = True)

    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=lobby,anchor = "nw")

    mainmenu.mainloop()


mainmenu.mainloop()
```

**I've been googling around for this kind of matter, and I think I've got a hint of making the 'selectfloor', 'floor7', 'room702' window as a children widget. But I'm still not sure how to make it happen.

Comment: Have you tried simply creating a list of all of the windows, and then destroying all but the first?

Comment: what do you mean by creating a list of all of the windows??

Comment: I mean, literally create a list, and save the windows to that list.

Comment: No, you don't have to press the button on each window. You simply step over the list, calling the `destroy` method on each item in the list.

Comment: but then i will have to press the button on each window to destroy it. What I'm stuck trying to do is pressing a 'home' button on the 4th window to destroy 2nd to 4th window and leave the first one alive. I've been searching a specific function that would let me do that

Comment: thank you for your insight, I will try your method

Comment: I'm very new to tkinter and I'm not sure how I can save the windows to a list...
Could you help me out with creating the list of windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the windows in a list, and then iterate over the list to destroy them.

Here's a simplified example. This example uses `Toplevel` windows rather than instances of `Tk`. It's not clear why you're using multiple instances of `Tk`, but in general you should only ever have one. This same technique works with any sort of widgets, however.

```
import tkinter as tk

windows = []
def delete_all_but_first():
    for window in windows[1:]:
        window.destroy()

def new_window():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    windows.append(window)
    window.title(f"Window #{len(windows)}")

root = tk.Tk()
windows.append(root)

del_all = tk.Button(root, text="Delete all", command=delete_all_but_first)
new = tk.Button(root, text="New window", command=new_window)
new.pack(side="top", padx=20, pady=20)
del_all.pack(side="top", padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

There's an optimization you can make if you use `Toplevel` instead of `Tk`, and if you always make the windows direct children of the root window. In that case you can just iterate over all children of root, and delete any window that is a top-level.

In this case, you don't need to maintain the `windows` list.

```
def delete_toplevels():
    for child in root.winfo_children():
        if child.winfo_class() == "Toplevel":
            child.destroy()

def new_window():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window.title(f"Window #{len(windows)}")
...
del_all = tk.Button(root, text="Delete all", command=delete_toplevels)
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Is it possible to add the del_all button to one of the toplevels that I created?

Comment: @SangminKim: yes, you can put anything you want in those windows.

Comment: This would complete my project. Thank you very much!